# Google Maps/Fusion Tables Javascript HTML won't display/visualize all polygon data (via colour scale)

Tags: javascript, html, api, google-maps, google-fusion-tables

I have a week left to finish this project so any help is greatly appreciated. I'm trying to get my javascript HTML code to work properly. For some reason, not all of the polygon colour values are being styled/visualized in the google map, as some of the polygon colours remain a default red, and therefore their value isn't being visually displayed. I'm not sure if it's a code error, or a built in styling limit. I am hoping someone can provide me an update javascript code so that it works.

Here is link, right click the page for the source code.
http://jonkowba.weebly.com/new-page.html

Thanks,
Jon

Answer (score 0):

There is a limit of 5 styles applied through the javascript API.

From the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#FusionTables):

> Limits
>
> You can use the Maps API to add up to five Fusion Tables layers to a map, one of which can be styled with up to five styling rules

Comment: so does this mean I can only add 5 different polygon color buckets?

Comment: You can add as many as you want via the FusionTables UI (I think).  It is only dynamically changing them via javascript that is limited to 5 styling rules.  Is that the problem you are running into?  Did you try defining them in the UI?

Comment: I did try the UI. It's just that it's a large scale operation with a lot of maps, so UI would require a lot of labour to constantly set the styling again and again, so a copy and paste of javascript would be much more ideal.

Comment: This ["answer"](http://support.google.com/fusiontables/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2669988) shows how to get the styles out of a FusionTable.  Perhaps you can set them as well (if not that would be a good feature request), then you could set up the styles you like in one table and copy them to all the others.